# How to reduce loading time in flash based website?

Tags: adobe-flash

I have a flash website and i continuously face problem of loading time it take long time to load how could solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design!  Can you include more information about your specific problem?  As it stands, it's borderline off-topic.  For example, if your flash is loading slowly because you use a ton of audio, that would not be a good question for this site.

Comment: The best solution is to get rid of your Flash web site. No one on an iOS device can see your site. That, alone, is argument enough to update.

Comment: @DA01: that was going to be my suggestion as well: don't make it Flash. It's clunky, slow, annoying, and hard to update easily.

Comment: @Lauren: I avoid Flash most of the time as well, but those are poor generalizations. Flash is certainly proprietary and lacks cross-platform support, but there's no factual basis for calling it any of those things. Compared to Java applets or trying to cludge JavaScript together to do the same thing, Flash offers much better performance. In fact, tests done comparing Flash vs. HTML5 for video playback showed Flash was significantly more efficient. Also, if you're unable to update your Flash site, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: "but there's no factual basis for calling it any of those things" unless you are on a Mac, where for years it's been clunky slow and annoying. (One of the reasons Jobs axed it from iOS).

Comment: I also added "hard to update easily" because, for example, if the site is in WordPress, the client can easily change text without knowing HTML or CSS. If the site is in Flash, you have to own Flash and know how to use it to change anything.

Comment: @Lauren: That's not true. Flash is a front-end technology. It can interface with any back-end you want. You can build a database-driven Flash site that is as easy to update as WP. Just like even though there are some static HTML sites, database-driven websites can still use an HTML front-end (as most do). And any professionally-developed Flash site would not require the operator to edit the Flash files to update.

Comment: @DA01: The tests I've seen show that Flash is slightly slower (around 10%) than HTML5 for video playback on OS X due to not having access to hardware acceleration, but there aren't many alternatives for the full range of Flash's multimedia features. And in fact Java applets and Silverlight are much slower on OS X than Flash. As far as annoying... I'm not sure what that means when talking about a multimedia platform.

Comment: But none of that changes the fact that Flash is clunky slow and annoying on OSX. ;)

Comment: I think it is significant that Simon mentions "a Flash-based website", rather than using Flash appropriately within a website...

Answer (score 2):

If you use many images, sounds or even videos you should check their file sizes. Try to avoid very big files by reencoding/compressing them to appropriate formats or exchaning them with smaller ones.

For pictures you can try to use vector based graphics (not for photos or similar) and convert all raw bitmap formats (such as .bmp) to PNG. Same for sounds: all raw wave files (such as .wav) should be encoded into MP3 for example.